# Two ajax calls with setinterval on the same page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have been trying to make a website where people share stuff, I am currently trying to display if user is online or not. This requires an ajax request but I already have a timer and an ajax request running every 5 secs. What can I do to make both run at the same time.
Here's my code:

```
setInterval(function() {checkiframe(); },5000);
function checkonline(){
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
           alert("true");
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "dbcheckpost.php?u=true", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
function checkiframe(){
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           if(xmlhttp.responseText === "true"){
            location.reload();
           }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "dbcheckpost.php?last=<?php echo $last; ?>", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    checkonline();
}
```

I also tried running two intervals but only one of them work.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I want them to work at different intervals.One is 5 secs while other is 10 minutes

Comment: Just giving you a tip. In a real world application, this is done with web sockets. Not intervals.

Comment: Do you always want both requests to send at the same time? Do you want them to send offseting? Do you want one to wait for the other one to respond?

Comment: @MaxBaldwin I have plenty of "real world applications" that use polling. Especially if they are running on shared servers.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin And for who cannot use websockets because has no shell command support in the host? Fckn;

Comment: @DustinPoissant I wanna learn polling... but is it so faster?

Comment: Websockets is instant bi-directional communication. Polling is slow and is a resource hog, but if your host does not support web sockets then polling is your only option, and it still is widely used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add both functions in the setTimeout anonymous function

```
setInterval(function() {
     checkiframe();
     checkonline();
},5000);
```

And remove "checkonline" from the "checkiframe".
If you whant for checkOnline to be executed after the checkiframe then it should be placed in the callback

```
function checkiframe(){
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        checkonline();
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           if(xmlhttp.responseText === "true"){
            location.reload();
           }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "dbcheckpost.php?last=<?php echo $last; ?>", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And if you want your function to be executed independently use to separate setInterval. 
Here example code that I've tested.

```
function f1(){
    console.log('1s');
}
setInterval(f1, 1000);
function f2(){
    console.log('5s');
}
setInterval(f2, 5000);
```

Comment: But it's correct to call the `checkonline` in the `checkiframe` function also.

Comment: Maybe the function's checkiframe() ajax call always returns responseText=true and the iframe is reloaded with location.reload();?

Comment: Then `checkonline` should be called when the request to `checkiframe` is made. IN TRUE IT'D BE BAD TO MAKE 2 requests AT THE SAME TIME;

Comment: Have you tried placing alert("true"); in the start of checkonline and xhttp.onreadystatechang callbacks start.

Comment: @kodvin but I need them at different intervals.

Comment: @user5674526 so just create two set intervals. setInterval(function() {
     checkiframe();
},5000);setInterval(function() {
     checkonline();
},10000);

Comment: @kodvin that way the checkonline function doesn't work while the other one does.

Comment: @user5674526 then its something wrong with checkonline() function. because it should work. I suggest find the lace where execution stops.(in the checkonline start, after ajax call or inside of the if statement)